# Show all drawable content in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, drawable, android-drawable

In my project I have got a lot of drawable content, and when I need to add new images to drawable I can put a same resource because I forget I have it already.

It is **not** about preview on XML file, this works well.

Any features in Android Studio to preview all my drawable contents without double-click on every resource? It can save lots of time.

I didn't find anything at Preferences, maybe some plugin or did I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Starting from Android Studio 3.4, you can use [Resource Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager?utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable&utm_source=android-studio-3-4), a new tool window for importing, creating, managing, and applying resources to your app's layouts. You can open the tool window by selecting

**View > Tool Windows > Resource Manager** from the menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Right click on drawable folder and click 'Show Image Thumbnails'.

[image]

Comment: hey, this is actually works. see link https://github.com/nanangarsyad/ss-collection/blob/master/ss-as-show-thumb.png. BTW, I was using android studio version 3.0

Comment: Works on 2.3.3 as well.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! A window with thumbnails to all drawables! **Hint:** to navigate within folders use "Level Up" and "Recursive" icons (1st and the 2nd). "Level Up" - activates only when you turn off "Recursive" representation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `Android Drawable Viewer` that can be installed from `Plugins` in `AndroidStudio`. After installing and restarting `Android Studio`, you will find a tab on the right side of the editor where you can find the viewer.

[image]

Click on that tab and you'll be asked to select the root folder for drawables. Do it, and after, everything will look like this:
[image]

Comment: this plugin does not support preview for webp.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Android Drawable Preview plugin. It shows content of the images instead of default icons when you expand drawables.

*It even renders vector xml drawables!*

Like this:

[image]

To install it: go to File > Settings > Plugins > search for Android Drawable Preview and click to find in repos. Install it and restart Android Studio.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Note/ when using 'Show Image Thumbnails' (as @Akhil Tawari suggested) in "Android" view as opposed to "Project" view, for image thumbnails of all drawables right click the "res" folder and not the drawables folder/s.

Answer (score -1):

You can right click on the folder and click open in files. This will allow you to open up the project folder in which you can more easily add and delete images and other files.